# Creation and persistence of a class property in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, memory, properties

I am writing a simple class to retrieve a signal `x` digitized at constant sampling rate `Fs`. Digitization begins at time `t0`. Given the signal length `N = len(x)`, the sampling rate, and the initial time, the signal's time base is uniquely determined. I rarely need to access the time base, but I would like an easy means of doing so when needed. Below, I've implemented a minimal working example of my desired time-base functionality using a `property()` decorator:

```
import numpy as np


class Signal(object):
    def __init__(self, x, Fs, t0):
        self.x = x
        self.Fs = Fs
        self.t0 = t0
        return

    @property
    def t(self):
        return self.t0 + (np.arange(len(self.x)) / self.Fs)
```

I'd like to know about the creation and "persistence" of the time-base property `Signal.t`. Take the example use case below:

```
    x = np.arange(10)
    Fs = 1.
    t0 = 0.

    sig = Signal(x, Fs, t0)
    print sig.t
```

When is the time-base array `t` generated? During initialization or dynamically when `print sig.t` is called? If the `sig.t` attribute is dynamically calculated, will it *persist* beyond the `print` command? (i.e. has memory been allocated to store the time base as an object attribute?).

While the above is a trivial example, my typical signals are very large, and I do *not* want the memory overhead of creating and storing the time base for every signal. I'd like an easy means of dynamically generating the time base on an as-needed basis, however; the time base should *not* persist as an object attribute after its one-off use (e.g. for creating a plot of the raw signal).

If the `property()` decorator does not provide this desired functionality (i.e. minimal memory overhead, ease of use on an as-needed basis), what should I be using? Simply a class method? Or is there a different, more optimal solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you access `sig.t`, the `t` function you decorated with `@property` is (re)run, and the result is used as the value of `sig.t`. That means the array is created on demand and never stored on the `t` object.

You seem to want this, but I'd be wary about it. Property accesses are generally expected to be cheap, and this property isn't. Consider making an ordinary method instead.

Comment: "Consider making an ordinary method instead." So just remove the `@property` decorator then?

Comment: @E.Davis: That, and of course, access it with `sig.t()` instead of `sig.t`.

Answer (score 1):

> When is the time-base array t generated?

When it is used.  i.e. when you write `print sig.t`

> If the sig.t attribute is dynamically calculated, will it persist beyond the print command? (i.e. has memory been allocated to store the time base as an object attribute?).

Nope.  The next time your code references `sig.t`, a new object will be created.

> If the property() decorator does not provide this desired functionality (i.e. minimal memory overhead, ease of use on an as-needed basis), what should I be using? Simply a class method? Or is there a different, more optimal solution? Thanks!

There are differing opinions here I suspect... you can modify the code so that you cache the value and return the same thing each call:

```
class Signal(object):
    def __init__(self, x, Fs, t0):
        self.x = x
        self.Fs = Fs
        self.t0 = t0
        self._t = None
        return

    @property
    def t(self):
        if self._t is not None:
            return self._t
        self._t = self.t0 + (np.arange(len(self.x)) / self.Fs) 
        return self._t
```

But here you have no way of telling the class that `t` should be re-computed unless you make a setter...

If `t` isn't going to change after initialization, then why not just make it a public property?

```
class Signal(object):
    def __init__(self, x, Fs, t0):
        self.x = x
        self.Fs = Fs
        self.t0 = t0
        self.t = self.t0 + (np.arange(len(self.x)) / self.Fs)
```

Comment: With regards to making the time base a public property: to reduce memory consumption, I usually do *not* want to create and store the time base. I just want a tool to easily create the time-base for rare, one-off use.

Comment: @E.Davis -- then I'd suggest using a regular method.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are dynamically generating the `Signal.t` value every time you access the attribute `t` because you are essentially calling Signal.t() to access it.So, you are not storing the value just returning it.

Whenever there is a  **@property** decorator being used around a class, it is quite common for that function to act as a "getter" for a "private"(not really) variable, and sometimes there is a "setter" for that "private" variable.

When I mean "private" I really mean attributes that are named to reflect that these attributes should not be accessed directly. However, in python you can access any attribute and so there isn't any private variables since python objects can be changed quite easy.

If you want to store your values, then you should do something like this.

```
    import numpy as np


    class Signal(object):
        def __init__(self, x, Fs, t0):
            self.x = x
            self.Fs = Fs
            self.t0 = t0
            self._t = None
            return

        @property
        def t(self):
            if self._t is None:
                self._t = self.t0 + (np.arange(len(self.x)) / self.Fs)
            return self._t

        @t.setter
        def t(self,value):
            self._t = value
```

The above example, will only calculate it once and store it inside `_t` , but you get the point. When the **@property** decorator is being used, usually there is an underlying variable that is used to retrieve and store a value.Hope that helps